# Hook 'beforeUpdate' in a sequelize model issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, hook

I am developing an API with nodejs/express/sequelize.

Actually when I am creating an user account. I got a Hook 'beforeCreate' which hash the user password thanks to bcrypt :

```
User.hook('beforeCreate', (user) => {
if (user.password) {
  user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
}
});
```

where `user.password` is the password I provided when registered.

This part is working well.

Secondly I got a function which update this user account. Logically I added a hood 'beforeUpdate' :

```
User.hook('beforeUpdate', (user) => {
console.log(user);
if (user.password) {
  user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
}
});
```

But I got an issue with that one because `user.password` is not my provided data in the PATCH request but the hashed password in my database.

I guess it is the model password and not the instance password... I don't know.
If someone could help me to get the query value it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_previousDataValues`

```
User.hook('beforeUpdate', (user) => {
console.log(user);
if (user.password) {
  user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.previous.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
}
});
```

Comment: It said 'cannot read property password of undefined' if I am using previousDataValues

Comment: Found it ! it was dataValues* ;)

Comment: @Cupkek05 dataValues and _previousDataValues are not the same. `dataValues` are the current values after updating.